# Are white holes hotter than our Sun?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, temperature, hawking-radiation, white-holes

A white hole is a theoretical region of spacetime and singularity that cannot be entered from the outside, although energy-matter, light and information can escape from it. In this sense, it is the reverse of a black hole, which can be entered only from the outside and from which energy-matter, light and information cannot escape.

Black hole event horizons can theoretically be hotter than our sun, but not from a planetary distance enough to sustain life on a planet orbiting that black hole.

Are white holes, instead, able to be hotter than our sun, as well as at a planetary distance enough to support life on a planet that is orbiting the white hole?

Comment: Preliminary question: does it make sense to talk about the temperature (or relatedly, the entropy) of a white hole?

Comment: What do the observations say?

Comment: We are not able to use GR to say what happens to a piece of matter after it falls into a black hole and hits the singularity. GR doesn't make a prediction about this situation, because the equations break down at the singularity. The time reverse of this situation is that the equations of GR do not say what (if anything) comes out of a white hole singularity. So GR does not make predictions in this case. A white hole is largely regarded as a "garbage in garbage out" solution of GR. Further, since we have never observed a white hole, there is no reason to think we can/should solve this problem.

Comment: GR = general relativity, for others reading

Comment: @safesphere I have no idea what definition of a white hole you are using, but I'm using a standard one that can be found, for example, in the first paragraph of [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_hole). " White holes appear in the theory of eternal black holes... This region does not exist for black holes that have formed through gravitational collapse, however, nor are there any observed physical processes through which a white hole could be formed."

Comment: @safesphere You seem to have written an answer to the question, but spread it over several comments.

Comment: who is @safesphere?

Comment: @safesphere There is much evidence that AGN luminosity comes from accretion.

Comment: @safesphere Just a bright dot? Nope. So many phenomena. Jets. Complicated accretion structures. Relativistic flows in inner accretion disks. Advection dominated accretion at low luminosity. And, recently resolved, the shadow of a black hole against its accretion disk.

Comment: @safesphere Sure, white holes can emit *anything*. Hypotheses that don't make predictions are not scientific. But even a low resolution image that matches the predictions of the black hole hypothesis is support for that hypothesis.

Comment: Has any image ever been taken of a **white hole** like the Event Horizon Telescope's capture of galaxy M87's **black hole** in April 2019?

Comment: Who says? Entire team in the documentary even says it's a black hole.

Comment: @safesphere If they are the same outside, they are the same as far as physics is concerned.

Comment: @safesphere This group is about physics, not untestable belief.

Comment: The M87 documentary did show how they tested if it was a black hole. There was no consideration of it being a white hole.